# how to correctly use system user in docker container

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm starting containers from my docker image like this:

```
$ docker run -it --rm --user=999:998 my-image:latest bash
```

where the uid and gid are for a system user called sdp:

```
$ id sdp uid=999(sdp) gid=998(sdp) groups=998(sdp),999(docker)
```

but: container says "no"...

```
groups: cannot find name for group ID 998
I have no name!@75490c598f4c:/home/myfolder$ whoami
whoami: cannot find name for user ID 999
```

what am I doing wrong?

Note that I need to run containers based on this image on multiple systems and cannot guarantee that the uid:gid of the user will be the same across systems which is why I need to specify it on the command line rather than in the Dockerfile.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I understood it correctly, you can get to the bash with the specific user using -u,

docker run -it -u root --rm --name=999:998 my-image:latest bash

Comment: thanks, Hemant. Your reply made me notice I'd typed the wrong command line into my question which I've subsequently edited.  I've been using the --user option all along, which is the same as -u.

Comment: Why do you need the container to run as a specific system user? Are you trying to access something mounted with a host volume/bind mount and need to avoid permission issues?

Answer (score 14):

This sort of error will happen when the uid/gid does not exist in the /etc/passwd or /etc/group file inside the container. There are various ways to work around that. One is to directly map these files from your host into the container with something like:

```
$ docker run -it --rm --user=999:998 \
  -v /etc/passwd:/etc/passwd:ro -v /etc/group:/etc/group:ro \
  my-image:latest bash
```

I'm not a fan of that solution since files inside the container filesystem may now have the wrong ownership, leading to potential security holes and errors.

Typically, the reason people want to change the uid/gid inside the container is because they are mounting files from the host into the container as a host volume and want permissions to be seamless across the two. In that case, my solution is to start the container as root and use an entrypoint that calls a script like:

```
if [ -n "$opt_u" ]; then
  OLD_UID=$(getent passwd "${opt_u}" | cut -f3 -d:)
  NEW_UID=$(stat -c "%u" "$1")
  if [ "$OLD_UID" != "$NEW_UID" ]; then
    echo "Changing UID of $opt_u from $OLD_UID to $NEW_UID"
    usermod -u "$NEW_UID" -o "$opt_u"
    if [ -n "$opt_r" ]; then
      find / -xdev -user "$OLD_UID" -exec chown -h "$opt_u" {} \;
    fi
  fi
fi
```

The above is from a fix-perms script that I include in my [base image](https://github.com/sudo-bmitch/docker-base/). What's happening there is the uid of the user inside the container is compared to the uid of the file or directory that is mounted into the container (as a volume). When those id's do not match, the user inside the container is modified to have the same uid as the volume, and any files inside the container with the old uid are updated. The last step of my entrypoint is to call something like:

```
exec gosu app_user "$@"
```

Which is a bit like an su command to run the "CMD" value as the app_user, but with some exec logic that replaces pid 1 with the "CMD" process to better handle signals. I then run it with a command like:

```
$ docker run -it --rm --user=0:0 -v /host/vol:/container/vol \
  -e RUN_AS app_user --entrypoint /entrypoint.sh \
  my-image:latest bash
```

Have a look at the base image repo I've linked to, including the example with nginx that shows how these pieces fit together, and avoids the need to run containers in production as root (assuming production has known uid/gid's that can be baked into the image, or that you do not mount host volumes in production).

Comment: I have tried to mount these two "-v /etc/passwd:/etc/passwd:ro -v /etc/group:/etc/group:ro"  and seems its not sufficient enough to overcome "Permission denied".

Comment: @teoring did you get to the second paragraph of the answer?

Answer (score 1):

It's strange to me that there's no built-in command-line option to simply run a container with the "same" user as the host so that file permissions don't get messed up in the mounted directories. As mentioned by OP, the `-u $(id -u):$(id -g)` approach gives a "cannot find name for group ID" error.

I'm a docker newb, but here's the approach I've been using in case it helps others:

```sh
# See edit below before using this.
docker run --rm -it -v /foo:/bar ubuntu:20.04 sh -c "useradd -m -s /bin/bash $USER && usermod -a -G sudo $USER && su - $USER"
```

I.e. add a user (`useradd`) with a matching name, make it sudo (`usermod`), then open a terminal with that user (`su -`).

**Edit**: I've just found that this causes a `E: List directory /var/lib/apt/lists/partial is missing. - Acquire (13: Permission denied)` error when trying to use `apt`. Using `sudo` gives the error `-su: sudo: command not found` because `sudo` isn't install by default on the image I'm using. So the command becomes even more hacky and requires running an `apt update` and `apt install sudo` at launch:

```sh
docker run --rm -it -v /foo:/bar ubuntu:20.04 sh -c "useradd -m -s /bin/bash $USER && usermod -a -G sudo $USER && apt update && apt install sudo && passwd -d $USER && su - $USER"
```

Not ideal! I'd have hoped there was a much more simple way of doing this (using command-line options, not creating a new image), but I haven't found one.

Answer (score 0):

1) Make sure that the user `999` has right privilege on the current directory, you need to try something like this in your docker file
    FROM

```
RUN mkdir /home/999-user-dir && \
    chown -R 999:998 /home/999-user-dir
WORKDIR /home/999-user-dir
USER 999
```

try to spin up the container using this image without the user argument and see if that works.

2) other reason could be permission issue on the below files, make sure your group `998` has read permission on these files

`-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 690 Jan  2 06:27 /etc/passwd
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 372 Jan  2 06:27 /etc/group`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So, on your host you probably see your user and group:

```
$ cat /etc/passwd
sdp:x:999:998::...
```

But inside the container, you will not see them in `/etc/passwd`.

This is the expected behavior, the host and the container are completely separated as long as you don't mount the `/etc/passwd` file inside the container (and you shouldn't do it from security perspective).

Now if you specified a default user inside your Dockerfile, the `--user` operator overrides the `USER` instruction, so you left without a user**name** inside your container, but please notice that specifying the `uid:gid` option means that the container have the permissions of the user with the same `uid` value in the host.

Now for your request not to specify a user in the Dockerfile - that shouldn't be a problem. You can set it on runtime like you did as long as that `uid` matches an existing user `uid` on the host.

If you have to run some of the containers in privileged mode - please consider using [user namespace](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/userns-remap/).